# Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Tags: mysql

I am executing the following query which apparently works fine on some servers and doesn't on others. What am I doing wrong?

*NOTE: I am not running it from phpmyadmin. I am running it from a MySQL Client (SQLYog)*

```
-- 1 --
SET @sql = NULL;


-- 2 --
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
               CONCAT('MAX(IF(s.Database = "', `Database`,'", `data`,"")) AS "',`Database`,'"')
              ) INTO @sql
FROM (SELECT t.user AS Users,
     t.db  "Database",
       c.Privileges,
       CASE c.col
         WHEN 'Select_priv' THEN IF(Select_priv = 'Y', '1 ', '0') 
         WHEN 'Insert_priv' THEN IF(Insert_priv = 'Y', '1 ', '0')
         WHEN 'Update_priv' THEN IF(Update_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') 
         WHEN 'Delete_priv' THEN IF(Delete_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') 
         WHEN 'Create_priv' THEN IF(Create_priv = 'Y', '1 ', '0')
         WHEN 'References_priv' THEN IF(References_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') 
        WHEN 'Alter_priv' THEN IF(Alter_priv = 'Y', '1 ', '0')
         WHEN 'Drop_priv' THEN IF(Drop_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') 
       END AS DATA
     FROM mysql.db t
     CROSS JOIN
     (
       SELECT 'Select_priv' AS col, 'Select' AS PRIVILEGES      
       UNION ALL SELECT 'Insert_priv',"Insert"
       UNION ALL SELECT 'Update_priv',"Update"
       UNION ALL SELECT 'Delete_priv',"Delete"
       UNION ALL SELECT 'Create_priv',"Create"
       UNION ALL SELECT 'References_priv',"References"
       UNION ALL SELECT 'Alter_priv',"Alter"
       UNION ALL SELECT 'Drop_priv',"Drop"
     ) c
 ORDER BY
    USER ) table1;


-- 3 --
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.Users,s.Privileges,  ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM (select t.user AS Users,
     t.db  "Database",
       c.Privileges,
       case c.col
         when "Select_priv" then IF(Select_priv = "Y", "1 ", "0") 
         when "Insert_priv" then IF(Insert_priv = "Y", "1", "0")
         when "Update_priv" then IF(Update_priv = "Y", "1", "0") 
         when "Delete_priv" then IF(Delete_priv = "Y", "1", "0") 
         when "Create_priv" then IF(Create_priv = "Y", "1", "0")
         when "References_priv" then IF(References_priv = "Y", "1", "0") 
        when "Alter_priv" then IF(Alter_priv = "Y", "1", "0")
         when "Drop_priv" then IF(Drop_priv = "Y", "1", "0") 
       end as data
     from mysql.db t
     cross join
     (
       select "Select_priv" as col, "Select" AS Privileges      
       union all select "Insert_priv","Insert"
       union all select "Update_priv","Update"
       union all select "Delete_priv","Delete"
       union all select "Create_priv","Create"
       union all select "References_priv","References"
       union all select "Alter_priv","Alter"
       union all select "Drop_priv","Drop"
     ) c
 ORDER BY
    USER )  s
                 GROUP BY s.Users,s.Privileges
                 ORDER BY s.Users');


-- 4 --
#SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

-- 5 --
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: An error "Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE" means that previous PREPARE statement fails.

Comment: I realize that, the queries are working fine by themselves, as well as giving successful outputs on several other MySQL instances. But giving  "Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE" error on some others as well. I mean one query cannot be right and wrong at the same time right? :/

Comment: The error message means that the most last ```PREPARE stmt FROM ...``` fails. No alternatives. You must find the source of this falling which either may be a result of incorrect SQL or may have another source.